# execute command and get working directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to execute a shell command in C++ and at the end I would like to fetch the current working directory of the executed process.
e.g. I executing the command `cd C:\`
then at the end of the command I want to get the directory `C:\`
and store it in a variable.

What I tried was [`pipe = _popen(cmd, "r")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen) to execute the command, but at the end of the command, even when [`_pclose(pipe)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pclose) wasn't called yet, when I called [`_getcwd(NULL, 0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd), I got the cwd of the running C++ program and not the changed cwd from `_popen`.

Does anyone know, how I could achieve this?

Comment: for process current directory use `GetCurrentDirectory` and `SetCurrentDirectory`. `pipe = _popen(cmd, "r") ` can not have any effect to your process directory

Comment: The shell command starts a new process and changes its own "current directory", not affecting any other process.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this:

I am creating a new Process of "cmd.exe" using [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) and injecting a piece of assembly code in the created process.

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/61271-how-to-get-current-directory-of-another-process/

I combined this with the [sample from msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles) for redirecting the stdin and stdout of the child process.

Comment: It would be safer to make a DLL to call `GetCurrentDirectory()` without writing assembly code, then use `CreateRemoteThread()` to inject the DLL into the target process, and have the DLL send the CWD back to your app using any IPC mechanism of your choosing.